# Dataframe write to cvs failed

Tags: python, dataframe

I am using the following code to save data into a cvs file:

```
filename='shareListing.csv'

allshares=pd.read_csv(filename)

i=0
for item in allshares['Code']:
    try:
        print item

        ebitdata=fdata(item)
        allshares.loc[:,('endDate')][i]=ebitdata[0]
        allshares.loc[:,('EBIT')][i] = ebitdata[1]

        print ebitdata[1]

    except  Exception, e:
        allshares.loc[:,('EBIT')][i] = ['NA']

allshares.to_csv('results.csv')
```

The shareListing.csv looks like this(endDate and EBIT columns are blank):

Code    shortName   endDate EBIT

000001.XSHE 平安银行
000002.XSHE 万科A
000003.XSHE PT金田A
000004.XSHE 国农科技
000005.XSHE 世纪星源
000006.XSHE 深振业A

and there is a function called fdata that returns "endDate" and "EBIT" for each specific item.

Upon executing, I got this:

```
000001.XSHE
E:/Python/py27/DataYes/Prices.py:91: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

```
 allshares.loc[:,('EBIT')][i] = ['NA']
000002.XSHE
C:\Users\ly\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:179: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

```
self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
E:/Python/py27/DataYes/Prices.py:85: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

```
allshares.loc[:,('endDate')][i]=ebitdata[0]
20901592186.7
000003.XSHE
```

I followed the documentation and changed the indexing function using `.loc` but still the same message, and the results.csv file only has the first item populated in the `endDate` and `EBIT` column, the rest is blank.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need change :

```
allshares.loc[:,('endDate')][i]=ebitdata[0]
allshares.loc[:,('EBIT')][i] = ebitdata[1]
allshares.loc[:,('EBIT')][i] = ['NA']
```

to:

```
allshares.loc[i,'endDate'] = ebitdata[0]
allshares.loc[i,'EBIT'] = ebitdata[1]
allshares.loc[i,'EBIT'] = 'NA'
```

Or if need missing value `NaN`:

```
allshares.loc[i,'EBIT'] = np.nan
```

Better solution is catch `Exception`s in function and return `Series`, then use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) for loop:

```
allshares = pd.DataFrame({'Code':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4]})


def fdata(x):
    try:
        #rewrite to your code
        if x != 'e':
            #return Series instead tuple    
            return pd.Series([x * 2, x * 3])
        else:
            #some sample exception for e value 
            allshares['not exist']

    except  Exception as e:
            #return Series instead tuple 
            return pd.Series(['NA', 'NA'])
            #for NaNs
            #return pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan])

allshares[['endDate','EBIT']] = allshares['Code'].apply(fdata)
print (allshares)

   B Code endDate EBIT
0  4    a      aa  aaa
1  5    b      bb  bbb
2  4    c      cc  ccc
3  5    d      dd  ddd
4  5    e      NA   NA
5  4    f      ff  fff
```

---

But if canot change function `fdata` create another one for cathc exceptions and return Series:

```
def fdata(x):
    if x != 'e':
        return (x * 2, x * 3)
    else:
        return allshares['not exist']


def func(x):
    try:
        return pd.Series(fdata(x))
    except  Exception as e:
       return pd.Series(['NA', 'NA'])
       #return pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan])

allshares[['endDate','EBIT']] = allshares['Code'].apply(func)
print (allshares)

   B Code endDate EBIT
0  4    a      aa  aaa
1  5    b      bb  bbb
2  4    c      cc  ccc
3  5    d      dd  ddd
4  5    e      NA   NA
5  4    f      ff  fff
```

Comment: Your code works a treat, very helpful. I never come across the apply() function and it is a big gain.
Could I ask now, if I have two argument in the function to be applied, how do you code? I try to follow the documentation:

allshares[['mkCap']]=allshares['Code'].apply(getmkcap,args=(allshares['endDate'],))

but it does not seem to work